# URL Rewrite for subdomains in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

How can I make URL rewrite rule for this url:
example.com/account/login.aspx

to this url:
me.example.com/login

So any request to the folder /account will rewrite to me.example.com. Also sub folders and file like /account/subfoler/file1.aspx will rewrite to me.example.com/subfolder/file1

I already set the DNS wildcard to the app and all subdomains will take to the same ip address. All I need is the url rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this in IIS 7.0 Url Rewrite

OR

Write your own handler to intercept incoming request

To achieve this you can implement the IHttpHandler and process the url redirection logic in t he ProcessRequest method

Here is a very good example http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30907/The-Two-Interceptors-HttpModule-and-HttpHandlers